# Finding probability of drawing $4$ white ball

Tags: probability

the probability of drawing $4$ white balls from an urn containing $10$ White ball , $4$ black and $3$ red balls ?

I have tried to use probability formula which is not working here

Comment: The problem as stated is vague.  Draw with or without replacement?

Comment: yeah that what i am not understanding !

Comment: and in how many draws?

Comment: Can you type the full question here, word to word?

Comment: yea i have typed word to word :)

Answer (score 3):

What's really not clear, is how many time you draw balls. I assume you do it 4 times, so the question breaks down into 2 cases:

Case 1 (with replacement): the successful outcome is to have $4$ successes out of $4$ trials, and the probability is fixed: $\big(\frac{10}{17}\big)^4$

Case 2 (without replacement): same, but the number of white and total balls reduces after each sample: $\frac{10}{17} \cdot \frac{9}{16} \cdot \frac{8}{15} \cdot \frac{7}{14}$